# AttributeError: module 'SimpleITK' has no attribute 'ElastixImageFilter'

Tags: python, installation, module, google-colaboratory

I need to use a library in my Python code which I run on Google Collab . MyOS Windows 10

I installed the package for that

```
!pip install SimpleITK==1.1.0
```

However, it still shows me the error :

> AttributeError: module 'SimpleITK' has no attribute 'ElastixImageFilter'

Is there a guide to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error. Resolved it by installing `SimpleITK-SimpleElastix` independently of the installed SimpleITK.

```
pip install SimpleITK-SimpleElastix
```